Wso2 apim allow request even after quota reach if creating new app and subscribe api again
Hi am looking solution for this scenario.

I deploy one api
through admin portal create subscription policy for 5 request count per month.
now from another username I logged in devportal
creating application and bearar access token
now I hot api 5 times then next request I got quota exceeded message from wso2 api

Now I delete previous created application and create new one and follow the same procedure creating key, api subscription
Now I got response from api.
Question is if I set subscription policy 5 request per month then why it's follow if I create new application.
How I can stop it completed when quota reached. Until and unless I allow some more request to subscription policy.
Any solution for this.
Thanks

Subscription policies are defined for specific subscriptions, that is, between a specific Application and an API. If you want to restrict access to a particular API after a certain number of requests, you may configure an Advance policy from the Admin portal and add restrictions for your API from the Publisher portal.
please refer,
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.3.0/design/rate-limiting/adding-new-throttling-policies/#adding-a-new-advanced-rate-limiting-policy
